# Get sip address, or username from identity in Teams Calling API

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a calling enabled teams bot, that receives calls. From the data it receives, we want to retrieve who is actually calling. For PSTN calls, this is ok. However, for Teams-to-Teams-calls (or SfB-Teams calls) we get the calling identity as (underneath example is SfB->Teams):

```
"identity":{
    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
    "onPremises":{
    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identity",
    "id":"<guid>",
    "tenantId":"<guid>",
    "identityProvider":"None"
    }
```

When all participants live in the tenant of the calling bot, we can retrieve all info (by using the graph API and just query the user with that objectID). But in the case the caller is from another tenant, how can we retrieve the displayname/sipadres for the identity?

For example, if I am being called, my teams client shows a display name. Now if the bot is called, how can it know the displayname (or sip address)?

I've tried to read out more properties using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/calls/..., however, that returns a 'call not found' consistently.

Comment: Did you added the other participants as Guest users within meeting?

Comment: I didnt add anything, as its a calling bot. So the bot is called by phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically we don't support calls from sfb with details of caller. From Teams client should be able to get caller object ID though

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean. My point is that I get the objectID (both for teams and SfB to teams calls), but I need the sipaddress/displayname. I want to know who is calling the bot. For example, if a teams client is called instead of the bot, you also see the displayname.

Comment: You can see the email within in the same tenant and if you try to call cross tenant it won't display.

Comment: So, to my question "But in the case the caller is from another tenant, how can we retrieve the displayname/sipadres for the identity?" you are saying, it's not possible? You get the tenantId and the objectID, but that's it. No other info at all? Isn't that weird?

Comment: @user1515791, Yes for sfb callers details won't display.

Comment: Its not only sfb, Teams to Teams (while not in the same tenant) behave the same. How does the Teams Client get that info? If I call sip from a different tenant to my teams client, i do see the sipaddress (and even the displayname for a split second)

Comment: Just to clarify, when external callers (not within the bot's Teams tenant) call the bot, Microsoft will prevent the caller identity from being known to the bot? Not even the caller's phone number?  Sounds like a bug /gap to me.  Can you please explain what security or privacy posture drives this?